# Kohana multiple default controllers based on roles

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I want to display completely different layouts for users in different roles on the root url of my application. I am currently achieving this using the following lines in bootstrap.php.

```
if (Auth::instance()->logged_in()){
  Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
   ->defaults(array('controller' => 'profile','action'     => 'index',));
}    
else{ 
 Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
  ->defaults(array('controller' => 'welcome','action'     => 'index',));
}
```

What is the best practice to achieve this in Kohana? Is it ok to add more lines for different roles in bootstrap.php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using [lambdacallback-route-logic](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/routing#lambdacallback-route-logic)

If allows you to modify the requested URL dynamically and much more cleaner than writing something in bootstrap.php

Comment: Thanks Kowser, can you explain how do I convert the logic/code above into lambdacallback logic?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont change basic template in ONE controller (and using the same route)? I think, your controller code doesn't differs if user logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:
Create an abstract class Controller_Rolebased where in before() method you can implement Role checking.
And then for example:

```
class Controller_Profile extends Controller_Rolebased
{
    protected $_accept_roles = array('user', 'admin'); // this array Controller_Rolebased class will use in before method.
```